# How to get relative path of file which is in project folder?

Tags: c#

I tried using `@"~\TestData\Test.xml"`, it is trying to get file from `bin/debug` instead of the project folder.

Comment: in which language you want it.in java or c#?

Comment: I fixed it by setting property of the xml file to "Copy Always"..

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by getting the parent of the current directory, using the Directory class in System.IO namespace. See code example.

```
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication15
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var projectFolder = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName;
            var file = Path.Combine(projectFolder, @"TestData\Test.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: var projectFolder = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName;

took me 2 x Parent() but works

Answer (score 4):

Go to Solution explorer -> right click on `TestData` folder and choose "Add New Item"

Choose "Resources file", rename it to `Resource` and click "Add".

[image]

You will get this screen (It can also be opened by double click on "Resource.resx in the solution explorer) [image]

Give name to the file and put the relative path in the value (may require one level up or down). To get the path you can now use

```
string path = Resource.XMLFile;
```